# Criteria for displaying last years records

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

As the title says, i need a criteria that will display all records of the previous year.

I've tried using `Year([SalesDate]) = Year(Date()) - 1`

Example if i use it now it will display all records from 2015. If i use it in 2017 it will display all records from 2016.

Cheers!

Comment: Also i tried this, it displays dates from 2015 but when i set my computer date to 2017 it displays 2015 and 2016 dates when i just want 2016 dates <=DateAdd("yyyy",-1,Date())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do. Alternatively, use *DateDiff* in your query:

```
Where DateDiff("yyyy", [SalesDate], Date()) = 1
```

Comment: The thing is i don't want to enter dates i just want to display all records from the previous year which the computer is on

Comment: That's what it does. Nowhere are you entering anything.

Comment: When i run the query it asks for a SalesDate?

Comment: Oh my. That's the _field name_ provided by yourself holding the date of the sales transactions.

Comment: Oh my also... i feel so stupid all this time i didn't know to change that with the field date set by myself, all this time i spent where it could've been as easy as this :(